# The type javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, vaadin

Установил eclipse Jee Neon 3 и импортировал ранее написанный проект на Vaadin, но я получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

The type javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Правильно настроил путь сборки, использую Java jdk 1.8 и Apache Tomcat 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уху., нашел ошибку. Можно исправить так: Проект> Свойства> Путь сборки Java> Библиотеки> Добавить библиотеку из вкладки библиотеки> Выберите время выполнения сервера> Далее> выберите Apache Tomcat v 7.0> Закончить> Хорошо